# Array.includes returning false in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome-extension

While trying to check if an item is in the array in a chrome extension, its returning `false` with `array.includes()` method.

Here is the code for checking

```
chrome.storage.sync.get({ 
        blockedUrl: []
    }, items => {
        let list = items.blockedUrl;
        let n = list.includes("example.com");
        document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = n;
    });
```

`console.log(list)` returns full array with all items (including example.com).

Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Comment: `includes()` typically works fine. So it's most likely, that `list` doesn't contain the values you think. Please post the EXACT output of `console.log(JSON.stringify(list))`

Comment: This seems to work fine. Please add code with console.log(list) right after list is defined.

Comment: Are you sure list is an array of strings?

Comment: Thanks. It was actually storing as array of arrays. Made mistake in my store method.